# How can I set the value of an hidden input tag with the value of the selected option of a select tag using JavaScript\JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xhtml, jquery-events

I am pretty new in **JavaScript** and **JQuery** and I have the following problem.

Into a JSP page I have some HTML code like this:

```
<form id="treeForm" method="post" action="http://localhost:7001/web/guest/link?p_auth=2QCM0Vgs&p_p_id=KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-4&p_p_col_count=1&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_templateDir=template&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_theme=css_xhtml&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_dynamicAttributes=%7B%7D&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_id=treeForm&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_struts.portlet.action=%2FkmCountryArea%2FkmCountryArea%2FsaveEventAttach&_KMCountryArea_WAR_KMPortlets_struts.portlet.mode=view" name="treeForm">
    <input id="folderId" type="hidden" value="" name="idFolder">

    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................

    <select id="treeForm_yourFolder" name="yourFolder">
        <option value="-1">Selezionare una Folder</option>
        <option value="CAMEX">CAMEX</option>
        <option value="NORTH AMERICA">NORTH AMERICA</option>
        <option value="BRAZIL">BRAZIL</option>
        <option value="CHILE NEW ANDEAN">CHILE NEW ANDEAN</option>
        <option value="IBERIA">IBERIA</option>
        <option value="ITALY_EUROPE">ITALY_EUROPE</option>
    </select>

    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
</s:form>
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet, the user can select a value (represented by the `<option>` value) from a drop down menu rendered by the `<select>` tag.

And also, in the previous code there is an **hidden input field** that have `id="folderId"`.

So now what I need to do is the following operation: when the user select an option from the menu rendered by the `<select>` tag a Javascript\JQuery script set the value of the hidden input tag (`id="folderId"`) with the value of the selected option.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for a change to the select, and on change assign the value of change to the hidden element:

```
$(function(){
    $('#treeForm_yourFolder').change(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        $('#folderId').val($(element).val());
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tbtawut - use an inspector (F12) to see change to hidden input.

Comment: folderId is an ID! => $("#folderId")

Comment: ok, so there was a typo. corrected. downvote for that? seriously.

Comment: Downvote != me! and another typo? => `$('#folderId').val(element.val())`

Comment: well then, thanks for pointing out the typo. an anonymous downvoter for no apparent reason. i can't see why. oh well that's life. that's stackoverflow.

Comment: no. that's not a typo. wrapping the element in $() ensures it's treated as it should be. i think a version of IE (or maybe jquery?) doesn't like it when you don't do that.

Comment: So, that's an error then as element is already a jQuery object! So, you are essentially saying `$($(this)).val()`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#folderId").val($("#treeForm_yourFolder :selected").val());
```

or

```
$("#treeForm_yourFolder").on("change",function(){
          $("#folderId").val($("#treeForm_yourFolder :selected").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query the select list inside the event function. You can simply use `this` keyword to refer to the select list.

```
$("#treeForm_yourFolder").on("change",function(){
              $("#folderId").val($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: $(this) will be in the scope of #folderid, not #treeform_yourfolder.

Comment: @dewd I have checked the code and it's working fine.

Comment: you're right. it does work. +1. i'm surprised as normally with jquery when a method is called on an object, "this" takes the form of that element. interesting. time for a bit of reading! ..probably only when an anonymous function is called! :)